# Three.js Water shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, simulation

I'm trying to update the "water noise" example from @oosmoxiecode to Three.js version r61 
http://oos.moxiecode.com/js_webgl/water_noise/

I've stripped out all the extra pieces and was able to debug and resolve the errors.

But now I'm at a point where the water seems to be running but the light isn't reflecting.

Here is a gist of the latest version: 
https://gist.github.com/tracend/7787307

And a demo of the same code: 
http://rawgithub.com/tracend/7787307/raw/three.water.html

Any help appreciated

Note: there are lights in the scene and the shader material is initiated with `lights: true`

Comment: The link you provide has way too much code, so the issue could be in many places (noise? normals? alpha value? etc). Is the light reflection effect dependent on the water running? I.e. you're able to get light reflection when there is no water running, but when you add the running water code you loose the light reflection effect? Remove all but the absolutely essential code; so if the effects are independent, then remove all running water code, replace with a static square, and post that code (rather than linking to something offsite which may lead to broken link for future viewers).

Comment: Thanks @Scholli, the code was too extensive to copy/paste that's why I used a gist. But most of those lines are the shaders which have not changed. I could split those to separate glsl files if that'll highlight the js better. The test you recommend is [already in place](https://gist.github.com/tracend/7787307/d88ece97cb84d6bb6ba28bc109b98322d2704d55#file-three-water-html-L444), if you comment line 443 and use 444 instead, which is a regular Phong material. So basically you get the lights with a regular material and no lights but movement with the shader material.